# Citing working paper that is now published

Tags: citing

I'm citing a journal paper `(A, 1995)`, which cited another paper when it was in working paper form `(B, 1994)`. `B` is now published in a journal `(B, 1999)`.

So should I be referring to `(B, 1994; A, 1995)` or `(B, 1999; A, 1995)`?

Comment: Which version of `B` did you read? The unpublished working paper or the published journal article? Are there significant differences between the two versions (can one even get hold of the unpublished version nowadays)? What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to quote specific lines? If this is just for a literature survey I'd definitely prefer the published article.

Comment: I can find the working paper but have read the published journal instead. It's part of my lit review and I'm citing one of their findings (not specific lines). (Edit) And the two versions looked exactly the same

Comment: @stevew ... When citing, you take care that the readers of your article/paper should have as better access to the work you are citing as possible. So, the published version should be preferred as a reference in your work because someone could possibly find it easier if wanted to take a look or something. Also, citing unpublished versions is always something that have to be our last option when we have to do it and only then.

Comment: Thanks all for the reply!

Comment: This isn't really a TeX question and might be a better fit for https://academia.stackexchange.com/, but for what it's worth I would say that usually the rule is that you should cite what you read. If you didn't read either of the two versions, but one is more readily accessible it might be a nicer touch to cite that version. In general it is preferable to cite the published version rather than the unpublished version. Of course depending on your exact situation you may decide to ignore one or more of those rules of thumb...